# Function move-uploaded-file is failing now before not failing

Tags: php, file-upload

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file1"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
      echo "<P>FILE UPLOADED TO: $target_file</P>";
   } else {
      echo "<P>MOVE UPLOADED FILE FAILED!</P>";
      print_r(error_get_last());
   }
```

I have the code above from [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php); I am getting to else and I don't know why.

Any reason for the above code to go to the else part?

FYI:

Before it is working great just now it is failing.

***When I said before I already run this on server and it is working fine. Just at the moment it stopped and I have no clue why.***

Comment: what error code do you get?

Comment: Did you check the folder permission ?

Comment: There are many reasons that earlier it was working and not now. What warning message do you get?

Comment: I will check for the error give me a minute

Comment: FYI it is working already in server. Just now it stopped i am still checking the error

Comment: make sure `$target_file` has file write permission

Comment: @brownman-revival check `if(is_writable($target_file) ) echo '1'; else echo '0';`

Comment: @aman give me a minute while i do it

Comment: @aman im getting 0 what does it mean?

Comment: You dont have write permission on $target_file. Thats what it means. Change the folder permission to either 755 or 777. Also check the owner of that folder.

Comment: i see thank you sir let me check again then i will be back if something happens..

Comment: @BrownmanRevival that means you don't have file write permission on you server

Answer (score 0):

I guess it was working locally but not now you've uploaded the script to a server? Sounds like a file permissions issue.

You need to check that Apache has permissions on the folder you're trying to upload to

Also check there is enough free space on the disk you're uploading to

Comment: When i said before i already run this on server and it is working fine. Just at the moment it stopped and i have no clue why

Comment: Okay, check the permissions on the folder as suggested, also check there is enough free space (sounds obvious but can be an issue)

Comment: enough could be an issue how to check for that?

Comment: what server are you using? Windows or Linux?